# No provider for Http! but the Module is imported

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the http module. After looking around for a bit I saw that the only two options for fixing this were to import the module (which i've done) or use HTTP_PROVIDERS which is deprecated for me.

I've imported it here:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this is my boot.ts

```
import 'core-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

And i'm trying to use it here :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers,Http} from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private _http:Http){}

}
```

but for some reason It's giving me the error: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Http!

The are the versions i'm using:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

any clue why I would still be getting this error after importing the module?

Comment: Is that a direct copy/paste from your package.json? `@NgModule` didn't exist until `rc.5`. You also have `http: ^2.0.1` while the rest are `rc.1`. They aren't compatible. If this is a new project, just start with `2.0.1` across the board.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `NgModule` was introduced in RC.5. But your dependencies is still using RC.1.

The current version of Angular2 is 2.0.1.

I will suggest following:

- backup your working directory
- update your package.json, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#create-and-configure
- delete node_modules and typings directories
- npm install
- test your code again